# How to change the header when a search is submitted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the Tire gem for search, and when I do a search query the header (top songs) stays the same. I'd like it switch to Search results instead when returning results.

I've been fooling around with the following code with no luck:

```
<% if Tire.search.results %>
<h6>Search results:</h6>
<% else %>
<h6>Top ranked songs</h6>
<% end %>
```

The above code makes the header 'Search results' even if no one has made a search query.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `empty?` on the collection because `Tire.search.results` returns an instance of `Tire::Results::Collection` which will never be falsy.

```
<% if Tire.search.results.empty? %>
```

See **[the source code](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/results/collection.rb#L46)**.

Comment: ah i see, but now it returns only 'top songs' even after performing a search query. How do I get this workin' ?

Comment: I'm guessin' that even though I haven't made a search there are still queries in the db which is why it is returning false for .empty?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea. I don't use Tire, I just am able to read and interpret the gem's source code. I can't speak to if/how queries are stored/flushed from your application.